# Boost Karma: generate default text when boost::optional is unset

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Consider the following program:

```
using FooVariant = boost::variant<std::string, int>;
using FooOptional = boost::optional<FooVariant>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooOptional()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

        foovar_ = bsk::auto_;
        start_ = -foovar_;
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooVariant()> foovar_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> start_;
};

int main()
{
    FooVariant fv = "foo";
    FooOptional fo = fv;
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fo) << std::endl;
}
```

As expected this will print `foo`. Likewise if I initialize `fo` simply with:

```
FooOptional fo;
```

Then the program will print nothing, again as expected. But instead of printing nothing, I would like to print `-` instead. So, I changed my rule for `start_` to:

```
start_ = (foovar_ | '-');
```

But this leads to a compilation error:

> alternative_function.hpp:127:34: error: no member named
>   'is_compatible' in
>         'boost::spirit::traits::compute_compatible_component,
>   int>,
>         boost::optional, int> >, boost::spirit::karma::domain>'
>               if (!component_type::is_compatible(spirit::traits::which(attr_)))
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

I also noticed that if I remove the `FooVariant` and instead make `FooOptional = boost::optional<int>` and update my generator, I can produce a crash if I pass it an unset optional. For example:

```
int main()
{
    FooOptional fo;
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fo) << std::endl;
}
```

Which leads me to believe I'm using the optional generation incorrectly. What is the right way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Investigating a little more I discovered something interesting. My modified code is:

```
using FooVariant = boost::variant<std::string, int>;
using FooOptional = boost::optional<int>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooOptional()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

        foovar_ = bsk::int_;
        start_ = (bsk::int_ | '-');
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, int()> foovar_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> start_;
};

int main()
{
    FooOptional fo;
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fo) << std::endl;
}
```

This works in that it will print the `-` or an integer value if one is assigned (which is not in the code pasted). However when I change my `start_` rule to this:

```
start_ = (foovar_ | '-');
```

I get a crash on an empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this seems not to work as you'd hope. Maybe a pragmatic simplification is to express "Nil" as a variant element type:

```
struct Nil final {};

using FooVariant = boost::variant<Nil, std::string, int>;
```

Now a default-contructed `FooVariant` will contain `Nil`. And the rule simply becomes:

```
    start_  = string_ | bsk::int_ | "(unset)";
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/drcIFJ4c5PPTHRhl)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

struct Nil final {};

using FooVariant = boost::variant<Nil, std::string, int>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooVariant()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

        string_ = '"' << *('\\' << bsk::char_("\\\"") | bsk::print | "\\x" << bsk::right_align(2, '0')[bsk::hex]) << '"';
        start_  = string_ | bsk::int_ | "(unset)";
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, std::string()> string_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooVariant()> start_;
};

int main() {
    for (auto fo : { FooVariant{}, {FooVariant{42}}, {FooVariant{"Hello\r\nWorld!"}} }) {
        std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fo) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
(unset)
42
"Hello\x0d\x0aWorld!"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a viable option for me since I am stuck with the `boost::optional<boost::variant<...>>` pattern.

Comment: Side question, does the order of the rules in your `start_` matter? I was under the impression (quite possibly incorrectly so) that the first sub-rule corresponded to the first type-possibility in the variant, and then the second and so on (in other words, I'd have written: `start_ = "(unset)" | string_ | bsk::int_`). But your code doesn't follow that pattern, so I guess order is unimportant and Karma/C++ will pick whichever rule works best?

Comment: The order doesn't strictly matter unless perhaps a branch caters to several attribute types at the same time. I'm having a hard time coming up with an example of that so maybe it's not applicable on the Karma side of Spirit. The point is that the attribute compatibility rules are type-based

Comment: I've been able to reduce this problem to something similar that seems more related to optional and variant. I am going to post another question since your answer does address the question here as asked.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got the problem. I'm just rarely motivated to fight really hard to get past the hurdles :)