# Boost Karma: writing a rule with boost::optional<boost::variant<...>>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

I am attempting to use a `boost::variant` within a `boost::optional` in a Karma generator. I've been able to reduce the problem to this:

```
using FooVariant = boost::variant<int>;
using FooOptional = boost::optional<FooVariant>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooOptional()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
        start_ = '[' << ( bsk::int_ | '*' ) << ']';
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> start_;
};

int main()
{
    FooOptional fop1;
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fop1) << std::endl;

    FooOptional fop2 = FooVariant{123};
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fop2) << std::endl;
}
```

The output here is:

```
[*]
[*]
```

Which is **not** what I was hoping for.

One of the first things I changed was more or less a sanity check by changing `FooVariant` to: `using FooVariant = int;`. This outputs:

```
[*]
[123]
```

And is what I want to see! So in my first code, the variant had only one type, so I tried adding a second type, just to see:

```
using FooVariant = boost::variant<int, double>;
...
start_ = '[' << ( ( bsk::int_ | bsk::double_ ) | '*' ) << ']';
```

But then we're back to:

```
[*]
[*]
```

Then I tried to add a rule specifically for the variant:

```
using FooVariant = boost::variant<int, double>;
using FooOptional = boost::optional<FooVariant>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooOptional()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
        foovar_ = (bsk::int_ | bsk::double_);
        start_ = '[' << ( foovar_ | '*' ) << ']';
    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooVariant()> foovar_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> start_;
};

int main()
{
    FooOptional fop1;
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fop1) << std::endl;

    FooOptional fop2 = FooVariant{123};
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fop2) << std::endl;
}
```

Which gives a compilation error:

```
alternative_function.hpp:127:34: error: no member named 'is_compatible' in
      'boost::spirit::traits::compute_compatible_component<boost::variant<int, double>, boost::optional<boost::variant<int, double> >, boost::spirit::karma::domain>'
            if (!component_type::is_compatible(spirit::traits::which(attr_)))
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

It looks like the template generation is trying to make sure that the `boost::variant` and `boost::optional` are compatible but for me the question is "why is it trying to make sure they're compatible at all?"

How can I make this work?

Comment: Two things. 1. I can't help but notice you're still omitting tiny bits /just/ making your code not-selfcontained (not many people here know by heart what headers to include). Also, 2. I see you are asking a lot of questions, perhaps you can review the answers you received and vote/accept those worthy of it.

Comment: I will include headers in future questions. And I always upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I told you in the other answer how I'd handle this: [Boost Karma: generate default text when boost::optional is unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671117/boost-karma-generate-default-text-when-boostoptional-is-unset/48672668#48672668)

Not only does that sidestep the issue, it also simplifies the AST/data types.

Now, since you're forcing me¹, I dug in. The problem arises from the fact that `foovar_ | '|'` is an *alternative-expression* and somehow it validates that the attribute must be compatible. During that check there is the assumption that

- If `a` has attribute `attr(a)` and `b` has attribute `attr(b)` then
- `a | b` should have `variant<attr(a), attr(b)`

It does do some logic checks (like when `attr(a) == attr(b)`) but not the logic check that if `attr(b)` is `unused_type` then it should be compatible with `optional<attr(a)>` too instead of just with `variant<attr(a), unused_type>` or even `variant<attr(a)>`.

Now, the why doesn't interest me that much². So, here's how you can *force* things.

```
    foovar_ = bsk::int_ | bsk::double_;
    fooopt_ = (bsk::eps(is_initialized_(bsk::_val)) | '*') << -foovar_;
    start_ = '[' << fooopt_ << ']';
```

The *key* is to encode it as something other than an *alternative-expression*. Here we simply trust `-foovar_` to say something, or not. In addition, we also do

```
bsk::eps(is_initialized_(bsk::_val)) | '*'
```

meaning: If the variant is initialized, that's all, otherwise, generate `'*'`.

Now you don't strictly need the third rule, if you like write-only code, you can just write:

```
    start_ = '[' << (bsk::eps(is_initialized_(bsk::_val)) | '*') << -foovar_ << ']';
```

### DEMO

Oh, I almost forget:

```
struct is_initialized_f {
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(boost::optional<T> const& opt) const { return opt.is_initialized(); }
};
boost::phoenix::function<is_initialized_f> is_initialized_;
```

Implements that helper Phoenix actor to check the initialization status.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab3a84055956ac36)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
using FooVariant = boost::variant<int, double>;
using FooOptional = boost::optional<FooVariant>;

template<typename OutputIt = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct FooGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIt, FooOptional()>
{
    FooGenerator()
        : FooGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
        namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

        foovar_ = bsk::int_ | bsk::double_;
        //fooopt_ = (bsk::eps(is_initialized_(bsk::_val)) | '*') << -foovar_;
        start_ = '[' << (bsk::eps(is_initialized_(bsk::_val)) | '*') << -foovar_ << ']';
    }

  private:
    struct is_initialized_f {
        template<typename T>
        bool operator()(boost::optional<T> const& opt) const { return opt.is_initialized(); }
    };
    boost::phoenix::function<is_initialized_f> is_initialized_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooVariant()> foovar_;
  //boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> fooopt_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIt, FooOptional()> start_;
};

int main()
{
    for (FooOptional fop : { FooOptional{}, {FooVariant{123}}, {FooVariant{3.14}} }) {
        if (std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(FooGenerator<>(), fop))
            std::cout << "\n";
        else
        {
            std::cout.clear();
            std::cout << "#Error\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[*]
[123]
[3.14]
```

---

¹ joke

² we'll get non-authoritative answers that rhyme with "someone forgot" or "it's a regression"

Comment: PS _"why is it trying to make sure they're compatible at all?"_ That's the only "why" that _does_ interest me, and the answer is: because C++ is a strongtyped language, and things would not compile if the types weren't compatible (it's not magic: it's all expressly programmed in the attribute propagation logic)

Comment: I understand about C++ being a strong typed language, my question was more why was it comparing those two types? The way I wrote my rule it seemed that the `optional` and `variant` should not have been being compared at that point. But you answered that in the main answer.

Comment: Note that the above solution only works in boost 1.56 and up (unless you specialize the attribute_size trait). See this patch https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/bdf4fd8d280c3ea191e0fd45cad0ccd2dbf6c297